# How to get (x, y) coordinates of displayed image?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, events, user-interface

Currently, I'm using a WPF `Image` control to display images. I want to do the following: On a `MouseUp`, `MouseDown` or `MouseMove` event, I want to get the coordinates of the point under the cursor, not with reference to the top-left corner of the control, but with respect to the actual coordinates of the displayed bitmap, which may have been re-scaled, or may have a different aspect ratio than the control itself. If an alternate control provides this functionality, I'd be equally happy to hear about it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'd also like so may to know it if the coordinates of the control were out of range of the image, due to a different aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the various [TransformTo*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms635661.aspx) methods of the `Visual` class to get, coordnates relative to a sepcific control, it will take all  transformation applied to the visual tree into account.

Also, if you attach `MouseUp`, `MouseDown` and `MouseMove` to the `Image` control itself, you should already get the correct coordinates from the `MouseButtonEventArgs` and if you use the mouse outside of the visual bounds of the control, you will not get those events, so you don't need extra code check for coordinates being out of bounds.

If your **actual** goal is to find out which acutal pixel of your bitmap image has been touched by the mouse (as you would need for a bitmap/pixel editing software) things get much harder because WPF uses virtual device indendent pixels that do not directly relate to pixels on the screen or pixels in a bitmap that has been rendered in an `Image` control. The `Image` control internally scales a bitmap image based on the DPI settings of the bitmap file itself and based on the DPI settings of operating system.

Comment: The last part is my real goal, to be exact. An image editing software is exactly what I'm trying to develop, and this is a major part of what's holding it back. An alternate control would be welcome, if there is any. Also, I didn't mean the bounds of the control, I meant the bounds of the image displayed within.

Comment: You sure should look for an alternative to the `Image` control in that case, you probably need to write one yourself.

Answer (score 3):

you can get the coordinates of the mouse by this way :

```
private void image1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
Point point = e.GetPosition(image1); //position relative to the image
Point point2 = e.GetPosition(this);  //position relative to the window
}
```

Hope that answered a part of your question.

Comment: I already knew this, but I'll mark it as helpful anyway. You're giving me access to the coordinates relative to the `Image` control, not really relative to the image inside it, and not really the coordinates of the Bitmap.